# Using Chronometer - After setText, Textview only shows the text for a second

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a time tracking app and want to have a stopwatch that can be started/paused/reset. When I press the "End Day and Save" button, I want the app to display the elapsed hours/mins/seconds in the TevtView underneath. It does, but only for a second and then it disappears. Where am I going wrong?

I tried creating a new method solely for updating the TextView but it doesn't show at all then.
If it helps, the min SDK version I have to use for this project is 23.

```
public void stopAndSaveChronometer(View v) {
    if (running) {
        chronometer.stop();
        running = false;
        time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
        h = (int) (time / 3600000);
        m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
        s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;

        Intent secondsIntent = new Intent(this,
                trackTodayActivity.class).putExtra("saved seconds", s);

        startActivity(secondsIntent);

        Intent minsIntent = new Intent(this,
                trackTodayActivity.class).putExtra("saved mins", m);

        startActivity(minsIntent);

        Intent hoursIntent = new Intent(this,
                trackTodayActivity.class).putExtra("saved hours", h);

        startActivity(hoursIntent);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

       if (extras != null) {
            seconds = extras.getInt("saved seconds", s);
            minutes = extras.getInt("saved minutes", m);
            hours = extras.getInt("saved hours", h);

        }

        // set up Strings to hold the times (already initialised as global variables)

        printseconds = Integer.toString(s);
        printminutes = Integer.toString(m);
        printhours = Integer.toString(h);

        // set up String to display in TextView (already initialised as global variable)

        displayTheTime = (printhours + " hours, ")
                + (printminutes + " minutes, ")
                + (printseconds + " seconds");

        // display the times in the Textview

        showMyTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printsavedTime);
        showMyTime.setText(displayTheTime);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: The function you have outlined above starts 3 different activities: how does that work?

Comment: I want to save the seconds/hours/minutes to the intents as I will be using them elsewhere in the app

Comment: Use debugger on the setText function and check if it's been executed more than 1 time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are launching 3 times `trackTodayActivity`? And is this activity useful?

To show the result this should be enough:

```
public void stopAndSaveChronometer(View v) {
  if (running) {
    chronometer.stop();
    running = false;
    time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    h = (int) (time / 3600000);
    m = (int) (time - h * 3600000) / 60000;
    s = (int) (time - h * 3600000 - m * 60000) / 1000;

    displayTheTime = String.valueOf(h) + " hours, "
            + String.valueOf(m) + " minutes, "
            + String.valueOf(s) + " seconds";

    // display the times in the Textview
    showMyTime.setText(displayTheTime);

  }
}
```

This could be done in the `onCreate` method from your activity:

```
showMyTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printsavedTime);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Just got to stick s, m and h into an intent now cos they need to go to another activity :)